# Removing Text after a combination of characters in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Column including values like this :

```
         12B2_10
         12C2_20
```

I want to delete what is written after _1 or _2 
My expected Result is:

```
         12B2_1
         12C2_2
```

format of column is nvarchar(50)

I tried this:

```
         update table  
         set column= ( SELECT SUBSTRING(column,1,CHARINDEX('_',column)+1),[ID] from table as z where z.ID=table.SID )
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(YourColumn,1,CHARINDEX('_',YourColumn)+1) 
FROM YourTable
```

In order to update your table use following query:

```
Update YourTable
Set YourColumn = SUBSTRING(YourColumn,1,CHARINDEX('_',YourColumn)+1)
```

Comment: That's absolutely correct but how do i update it? i want to replace it with the new trimmed values

Answer (score 2):

You can try this also

```
UPDATE table
SET    column = LEFT(column, CHARINDEX('_', column) + 1)
```